# Mobilefirst 6.3 using java spring on serverside

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mobilefirst

is it possible to use java spring api's (rest api) on java server side code in mobilefirst 6.3 server. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

In MobileFirst 6.3 (and previous versions) the server side Java code has two purposes:

1. Custom login modules and authenticators
2. Custom Java code that can be invoked from a MobileFirst adapter (written in JavaScript)

MobileFirst 6.3 does not officially support exposing spring REST services using this custom Java code

However, 
In MobileFirst 7.0 or above, it is possible to use Java adapters. Java adapters expose REST service implemented with JAX-RS standard (not spring REST). Even though JAX-RS isn't spring REST, it is quite similar and should not be a big problem to migrate from spring REST to JAX-RS.

Comment: BTW, take a look at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/24/MobileFirst-spring-integration-in-java-adapters/ a simple way to use spring in MobileFirst 8.0 Java adapters